# Integration by parts constant before the integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that the formula for integration by parts is $S=\int udv=uv-\int vu'dx$ but what happens if my integral has some constant say $5S$... where would I put the constant?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c \int f(x) dg(x) = c\left(f(x)g(x) - \int g(x)df(x)\right) = cf(x)g(x) - c\int g(x)df(x)$$

Comment: So on both equations?

Comment: Yeah, recall that: $a= b \implies ca = cb$

Comment: should be another question but... can I use this formula if dx isn't the same as x?

Comment: I don't understand your question. dx the same as x? What does that mean?

Comment: I meant the x inside the dx to be same as one of the x's in either f(x) or g(x)

Comment: should be the same